# How to collect AWS alarm ARNs into a string in Terraform to use in a CloudWatch Dashboard creation JSON?

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I am creating a set of CloudWatch alarms using Terraform like so:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "lambda_concurrent_executions" {
  for_each = toset(var.function_names)

  alarm_name          = "${each.key}-concurrent-executions"
  alarm_description   = "The number of function instances that are processing events."
  namespace           = "AWS/Lambda"
  metric_name         = "ConcurrentExecutions"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  period              = "60"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  threshold           = "100"

  treat_missing_data = "ignore"

  dimensions = {
    FunctionName = each.key
  }

  alarm_actions = var.alarm_actions
  ok_actions    = var.alarm_actions
}
```

so it uses `for_each` list of function names.

Next, I need to create a CloudWatch dashboard. It is apparently created by supplying a JSON with relevant names ([documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_dashboard)):

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = "my-dashboard"

  dashboard_body = <<EOF
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "alarm",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 12,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "title": "Alarms",
                "alarms": [
                    "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:167170067742:alarm:mylambda-concurrent-executions",
                    "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:167170067742:alarm:mylambda-concurrent-executions-2",
                    "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:167170067742:alarm:mylambda-concurrent-executions-3",
                    "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:167170067742:alarm:mylambda-concurrent-executions-4",
   
/// ... and so on
}
EOF
}
```

How can I collect created alarms ARNs in a variable and insert these in the Dashboard JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `for`-loop over your `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` resources.

I simulated your setup with the following:

```
variable "function_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["fun-1", "fun-2", "fun-3"]
}

resource "null_resource" "lambda_concurrent_executions" {
  for_each = toset(var.function_names)

  triggers = {
    function_name = each.key
  }
}
```

And then something like this enables me to loop over the by `for_each` generated resources:

```
join(", ", [for i in null_resource.lambda_concurrent_executions : format("\"%s\"", i.id)])
```

So for your example the section where you need your alarm ARNs in would become:

```
"alarms": [${join(", ", [for a in aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.lambda_concurrent_executions : format("\"%s\"", a.arn)])}]
```

(Btw. it should also work with a [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) but I could only make it work with a traditional `for`-loop.)